# Soap Header is not generated in webservice and in wsdl file

Tags: soap, jax-rs, soapui, jax-ws, soap-client

I am new to Soap API. I am creating soap-API, for which I have **.xsd** file, which contains request and response part and also User Credentials. When my soap is getting build , **.wsdl** file generated , but doesn't have header part, means my request doesn't have header part.Although I am using @soapHeader , but it's not working.
below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/finance"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/finance"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<s:element name="UserCredentialsHeaders">
<s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserID"
            type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password"
            type="s:string" />
    </s:sequence>
    <s:anyAttribute />
</s:complexType>
</s:element>

<s:element name="GetPendingPaymentsRequest">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FI_ID"
                type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PFS_ID"
                type="tns:ArrayOfInt" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LangCode"
                type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>

<s:complexType name="ArrayOfInt">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="int"
            type="s:int" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="GetPendingPaymentsResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                name="GetPendingPaymentsResult" type="tns:PTranResponseList" />
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="PTranResponseList">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
            name="PTranResponseDetaillist" type="tns:ArrayOfPTranResponse" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfPTranResponse">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            name="PTranResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:PTranResponse" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="PTranResponse">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PFS_ID"
            type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReturnCode"
            type="s:long" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ErrorDesc"
            type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReturnCount"
            type="s:long" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PtranList"
            type="tns:PTranList" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="PTranList">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
            name="PTranDetaillist" type="tns:ArrayOfPTranItem" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfPTranItem">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            name="PTranItem" nillable="true" type="tns:PTranItem" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="PTranItem">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentDate"
            type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentAmount"
            type="s:double" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
            name="PaymentCurrency" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DebitTransit"
            type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DebitAccount"
            type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PayeeName"
            type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentType"
            type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Status"
            type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
            name="NumberOfApproversRemaining" type="s:int" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

</s:schema>

My config class:

```
 @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetPendingPaymentsRequest")
  @ResponsePayload
  public GetPendingPaymentsResponse getPendingpayments(@RequestPayload GetPendingPaymentsRequest request,
      @SoapHeader(value = "{" + NAMESPACE_URI + "}"+"/UserCredentialsHeaders") SoapHeaderElement soapHeaderElement) throws Exception {
    GetPendingPaymentsResponse response = new GetPendingPaymentsResponse();

    response.setGetPendingPaymentsResult(
        pendingPaymentProcessor.getPendingPayments(request.getFIID(), request.getPFSID(), request.getLangCode()));
    return response;
  }
```

Generated WSDL:

```
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://www.example.com/finance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/finance" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/finance">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/finance">
<s:element name="UserCredentials" type="tns:UserCredentials"/>
<s:complexType name="UserCredentials">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UserID" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
<s:anyAttribute/>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="GetPendingPaymentsRequest">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FI_ID" type="s:int"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PFS_ID" type="tns:ArrayOfInt"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LangCode" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfInt">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="int" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="GetPendingPaymentsResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GetPendingPaymentsResult" type="tns:PTranResponseList"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="PTranResponseList">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PTranResponseDetaillist" type="tns:ArrayOfPTranResponse"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfPTranResponse">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="PTranResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:PTranResponse"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="PTranResponse">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="PFS_ID" type="s:int"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ReturnCode" type="s:long"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ErrorDesc" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ReturnCount" type="s:long"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PtranList" type="tns:PTranList"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="PTranList">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PTranDetaillist" type="tns:ArrayOfPTranItem"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfPTranItem">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="PTranItem" nillable="true" type="tns:PTranItem"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="PTranItem">
<s:sequence>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PaymentDate" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="PaymentAmount" type="s:double"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PaymentCurrency" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="DebitTransit" type="s:int"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DebitAccount" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PayeeName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PaymentType" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Status" type="s:string"/>
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="NumberOfApproversRemaining" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetPendingPaymentsRequest">
<wsdl:part element="tns:GetPendingPaymentsRequest" name="GetPendingPaymentsRequest"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetPendingPaymentsResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:GetPendingPaymentsResponse" name="GetPendingPaymentsResponse"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="PFSSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="GetPendingPayments">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetPendingPaymentsRequest" name="GetPendingPaymentsRequest"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetPendingPaymentsResponse" name="GetPendingPaymentsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="PFSSoapSoap12" type="tns:PFSSoap">
<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPendingPayments">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.example.com/finance/GetPendingPayments"/>
<wsdl:input name="GetPendingPaymentsRequest">
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="GetPendingPaymentsResponse">
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="PFSSoapSoap11" type="tns:PFSSoap">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPendingPayments">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.com/finance/GetPendingPayments"/>
<wsdl:input name="GetPendingPaymentsRequest">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="GetPendingPaymentsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PFSSoapService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:PFSSoapSoap12" name="PFSSoapSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://example:80/ws"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port binding="tns:PFSSoapSoap11" name="PFSSoapSoap11">
<soap:address location="http://example:80/ws"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai , Yes , means in soap envelop request it should have header and body part.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai , I want header in request body only, for which I am using SoapHeader annotation , but Header is not coming in request , when I load .wsdl file in soapui.